# Unix socket, SOCK_SEQPACKET vs SOCK_DGRAM

Tags: c, unix

It seems there's atleast 3 different local/unix socket types (`AF_UNIX`) , `SOCK_STREAM`, `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_SEQPACKET`.

While I know that a `SOCK_STREAM` gives you a bi-directional byte stream, like TCP or a bidirectional pipe, and the other two gives you a messge/packet API, what's the difference between a unix socket of `SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_SEQPACKET` ?

As these are local only, I can't think of a good reason someone would implement `SOCK_DGRAM` in a manner it could reorder packets.

Also, does `SOCK_DGRAM`/`SOCK_SEQPACKET` employ flow control, or can messages be dropped in case of slow readers ?

Comment: IIRC, SOCK_DGRAM will give you one message at a time, while SOCK_SEQPACKET(for protocols which support it) will allow you to read multiple datagrams at a time, but always give atomic reads of datagrams, vice SOCK_STREAM where you need to parse the message boundaries yourself.

Comment: Just a comment SOCK_SEQPACKET is used in AX.25 (Ham radio protocol) see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040205/connect-error-no-route-to-host

Answer (score 32):

Here is a good article on the intended use case for `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, the fact that it's not really available in the IP protocol families, and how you can get the same thing with existing TCP semantics:

http://urchin.earth.li/~twic/Sequenced_Packets_Over_Ordinary_TCP.html

Note that `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is much closer in behavior to `SOCK_STREAM` than to `SOCK_DGRAM`.

Citing from the referenced website:

> The SOCK_SEQPACKET socket type is similar to the SOCK_STREAM type, and is also connection-oriented. The only difference between these
>   types is that record boundaries are maintained using the
>   SOCK_SEQPACKET type. A record can be sent using one or more output
>   operations and received using one or more input operations, but a
>   single operation never transfers parts of more than one record. Record
>   boundaries are visible to the receiver via the MSG_EOR flag in the
>   received message flags returned by the recvmsg() function. It is
>   protocol-specific whether a maximum record size is imposed.

Comment: It does talk more about TCP/IP than PF_UNIX (PF_LOCAL) sockets though.. So far it seems the only real difference between a SOCK_SEQPACKET and SOCK_DGRAM local socket is that a SOCK_SEQPACKET socket is connection oriented, but i'm still not sure..

Comment: Well, this answer is wrong. The question asks specifically about PF_UNIX, and while the ideal SOCK_SEQPACKET would be one abstraction level higher than SOCK_STREAM (providing messages boundaries over it), the implementations are not so idealistic. According to [this](http://osdir.com/ml/ietf.tsvwg/2005-12/msg00005.html), PF_UNIX implementations are very much liker SOCK_DGRAM, except for... well, I don't really know, that is why I came into this page, and no answer seems satisfactory. This answer applies only to more elaborated network protocols that implements SOCK_SEQPACKET as supposed to be.

Comment: @lvella: The link I cited in my answer not only explains how to emulate SOCK_SEQPACKET on TCP (which is not relevant to OP's question) but also the motivations of SOCK_SEQPACKET, which I believe are one of the main topics OP was asking about.

Comment: @R.. The problem is, whatever is the motivation for SOCK_SEQPACKET, that is not how it works on AF_UNIX, and I still don't why it exists, since the implementation lacks precisely what should differentiate it from SOCK_DGRAM (message boundary markings that are independent from the low-level datagram).

Answer (score 13):

SOCK_SEQPACKET gives you the guarantees of SOCK_STREAM (i.e., preservation of ordering, guaranteed delivery, no duplication), but with delineated packet boundaries just like SOCK_DGRAM. So, basically it's a mix of the two protocol types.

In the TCP/IP-family, [SCTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_Control_Transmission_Protocol) implements both SOCK_STREAM (TCP-like) and SOCK_SEQPACKET. Unfortunately it is not stock-available on Windows.

Answer (score 13):

I think the main difference here is that `SOCK_SEQPACKET` is *conneciton-oriented*, while `SOCK_DGRAM` is not.

This will mostly matter on the *server* side of the connection (the process that listens on the UNIX socket) when there are *multiple* client processes talking to it:

With `SOCK_DGRAM`, you would get interleaved client datagrams directly on the listening socket. With `SOCK_SEQPACKET`, you would spawn a separate *client* socket for each client using `accept`, thus receiving datagrams from each client separately.

Quoting `man 3 accept`:

> The  accept() system call is used with connection-based socket types (SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_SEQPACKET).

Answer (score 6):

socket(2) linux-provided manpage: “DGRAM: datagrams (connectionless, unreliable messages), SEQPACKET: sequenced, reliable, [two-way] connection-based data transmission path for  datagrams". Significant difference.

unix(7) linux-provided manpage says: “SOCK_DGRAM, for a **datagram-oriented** socket that preserves message boundaries [but not necessarily order] [...] SOCK_SEQPACKET, for a **connection-oriented** socket that preserves message boundaries and delivers messages in the order that they were sent.”

The standard *permits* that you get reordered packets with SOCK_DGRAM. (In other words, if an OS hands them to you in order, that is an implementation-specific feature. Or just pure timing luck.)

There is flow control in the af_file/af_unix implementation in Linux, but that does not need to correlate with standard specified behavior at all.

Answer (score 0):

Like TCP and UDP sockets, there are SCTP(stream control transmission protocol) sockets which has two forms, (one to one) and (one to many) between endpoints. One to one uses SOCK_STREAM and one to many uses SOCK_SEQPACKET