# Terraform: Unable to Communicate with Google Cloud Platform Infrastructure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have both the latest Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Cloud SDK (`gcloud`):

```sh
gcloud version

#=>

Google Cloud SDK 356.0.0
beta 2021.09.03
bq 2.0.71
core 2021.09.03
gsutil 4.67
```

and the latest Terraform CLI (`terraform`):

```sh
terraform version

#=>

Terraform v1.0.6
```

installed.  When I attempt to `apply`, `plan` or `refresh` a Terraformed Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster:

```sh
terraform plan -target=google_container_cluster.test

#=>

google_container_cluster.test: Refreshing state... [id=projects/. . ./test]
╷
│ Error: Error when reading or editing Container Cluster "test": Get "https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/. . ./test?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": dial tcp [xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xxx]:443: connect: no route to host
│
│   with google_container_cluster.test,
│   on container_cluster.tf line 1, in resource "google_container_cluster" "test":
│    1: resource "google_container_cluster" "test" {
│
╵
```

I encounter the error above.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a connection error.  There doesn't seem to be anything misconfigured on your side if you have been able to `apply`, `plan` or `refresh` previously.

If you are able to fix the external connection issue that is separate from both Terraform and the Cloud SDK, you *should* be able to use Terraform with remote GCP infrastructure again.

Terraform communicates with GCP using REST; e.g., the route found within your error above is the route Terraform is using to read the remote GKE cluster.  You can learn more about the:

> no route to host

error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19040611).