# Unix domain socket name in go language

Tags: sockets, unix, go

The **net** package in go provides this function:

```
func ResolveUnixAddr(net, addr string) (*UnixAddr, error)
```

The string parameter `net` gives the network name, "unix", "unixgram" or "unixpacket".

I guess the the network name's meaning as:

- *unixgram*: as type SOCK_DGRAM in socket() function, used by ListenPacket() in net package.
- *unixpacket*: as type SOCK_STREAM in socket() function, used by Listen() in net package.
- *unix*: either

Am I right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the `unixSocket` function in [`net/unixsock_posix.go`](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/unixsock_posix.go#L16), we have:

```
var sotype int
switch net {
case "unix":
        sotype = syscall.SOCK_STREAM
case "unixgram":
        sotype = syscall.SOCK_DGRAM
case "unixpacket":
        sotype = syscall.SOCK_SEQPACKET
default:
        return nil, UnknownNetworkError(net)
}
```

So you're right about `unixgram` being a datagram socket, but it is `unix` that refers to the the stream type socket and `unixpacket` refers to a sequential packet socket (i.e. data is sent in packets as with datagram sockets, but they are delivered in order).

Comment: I find [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10104082/unix-socket-sock-seqpacket-vs-sock-dgram) for SOCK_SEQPACKET.

Comment: Think of SEQPACKET like STREAM, but each `recv` operation on the socket will correspond to a `send` from the other end.  That is, the write boundaries will be maintained when read by the other party.