# Why sends of "large" array/slice using net/rpc/jsonrpc codec over unix socket connection hang?

Tags: go, rpc, packet, unix-socket, json-rpc

I'm trying to send an array of data as an rpc reply using golang's built-in `net/rpc` server and client and the `net/rpc/jsonrpc` codec. But I'm running into some trouble.

The data I'm sending is around 48 bytes, and the client will just hang in `client.Call`.

I've made a playground that replicates the problem:
https://go.dev/play/p/_IQ9SF7TSdc

If you change the constant "N" in the above program to 5,
things work as expected!

Another playground shows how the issue seems to crop up only when the slice/array in question exceeds 49 bytes:
https://go.dev/play/p/R8CQa0mv7vB

Does anyone know what might be the issue? [Golang's tests for the array and slice data types](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.3:src/net/rpc/jsonrpc/all_test.go;drc=2580d0e08d5e9f979b943758d3c49877fb2324cb;l=70) are not exactly designed for "large" arrays in mind. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason to use "unixpacket" instead of "unix"? I conjure, your issue will be resolve once you move to "normal" bytestream-oriented connections over the Unix-domain sockets.

Comment: From the socket manpage: `SOCK_SEQPACKET: Provides a sequenced, reliable, two-way connection-based data transmission path for datagrams of fixed maximum length; a consumer is required to read an entire packet with each input system call.`
That is of course not going to work for a service which is not designed to use it, and is expecting a stream protocol.

Comment: @kostix thank you so much! that did the trick. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955887/7102100) explaining how the network type affects the underlying socket call. But I'd be interested to know why the limit is short on the unixpackets. Anyways you have my deepest thanks.

Comment: Ah thanks @JimB, i didn't know rpcs where supposed to be over a stream. My thanks.

Comment: Anything using a packet-based protocol must be designed to do so. You have a fixed length reads and writes, incomplete reads will discard data, and large writes will get truncated.

Comment: While we're at this, please note that the problem you were experiencing was not a deadlock. I mean, not every kind of apparent hang of some process is a deadlock. A deadlock is a very specific issue occuring when one or more parallel flows of execution try to mutually acquire two or more resources using a specific pattern of accessing them. Please see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock).

Comment: yeah but when the program runs it says `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!` So I think it probably is a deadlock. Anyways, I would change the title back so people searching end up in the right place

Comment: The deadlock is only a symptom caused by your particular example. Most people wouldn't be implementing both sides of the connection in the same process (except for toy examples), and even then may still have network loops which could technically proceed and won't trigger deadlock detection. The deadlock isn't really relevant, the stream is corrupted causing the sender and/or receiver to hang.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. in my non-toy code I actually didn't get a deadlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line where the listener is set up:

```golang
listener, err := net.ListenUnix("unixpacket", &net.UnixAddr{RPCPath, "unixpacket"})
```

Don't use `unixpacket`. It corresponds to the underlying SOCK_SEQPACKET which is not a stream protocol. Likely large files were separated into packets in a way the receiver was not able to process. Use `unix` instead, which corresponds to SOCK_STREAM.
See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22955887/7102100)
for more.